# OS dependencies for app running on Google App Engine Flex (pdftotext library)

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a Python app deployed on Google App Engine.

My application takes in a pdf file path, retrieves and downloads the file, then converts the file to text using the python library [pdftotext](https://pypi.org/project/pdftotext/) before the data is further processed.

`pdftotext` requires additional OS dependencies that I can't just add to my `requirements.txt`:

`sudo apt-get install build-essential libpoppler-cpp-dev pkg-config python-dev`

Is it possible to have OS dependencies for applications deployed on App Engine (serverless)? If so, how can I add those dependencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your application requires additional operating-system level dependencies, you will need to use a [custom runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes) to install the appropriate packages.